# onNavigationItemSelected not called

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, navigationview

Please don't mark this questions as Duplicate, I know there's many question like this in this site.

The onNavigationItemSelected() on My `MainActivity.kt` doesn't invoked while i already `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` to `this` and put `NavigationView` as the last child on `DrawerLayout` tag. I dont understand anymore, why this problem occured.

You can check my code below

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.googlelike

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.example.googlelike.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        navigationView = binding.navView
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(p0: MenuItem): Boolean {
        Log.i("MainActivity","Item CLICKED")

        return true
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` is almost never needed when you use Navigation and `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController`, since that is doing the correct thing for you already as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer). If you just want logging, you should [listen for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events).

Comment: how to do that without `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the buttons to open an activity or want to do anything else you can simply do one thing
in the navigation menu items in item write this as

```
<item
   android:Onclick=any function you can name of your choice/i am taking it as "open profile"
   android:icon="icon"
   android:tile="title"></item>
```

and in main activity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
    ...
}

//let my activity name be profile
fun "open profile"(menu item: Menu item){
    val intent = Intent(this, profile::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

hope it was helpful for you if want any furthur info then please let me know i can help you with that istead of using that long methods this method is more easy and eficient and if your navigation is bottom navigation menu and want to switch between fragments then please let me know i know a very easy method for it.

Comment: it worked on me, but this is not efficient. can we do that without assigning onClick on every item?

Comment: we have to set on click in my opinion there is no other way